# deploy.prototxt in Caffe model

Tags: python, opencv

I am running into this problem when running my code:

```
    model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("deploy.prototxt", "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel")
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1126: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```

I Believe it is coming from when I run this line of code and am not sure what to do about it. I thought it was because I didn't have this file saved with the code but I am not entirely sure what this file is and does:

```
# Load the SSD model
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("deploy.prototxt", "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and to make a [mre]. I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but I added the tag for it and fixed up the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

it's my first time in Stackoverflow, so i'm sorry i still don't know how to use it. However, from my understanding you want to use the opencv Caffe model for face detection. To do this you need to download the the two files:
'res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel' and 'deploy.prototxt.txt'. You can do that from here:
https://github.com/Shiva486/facial_recognition.
Then put those files in the same folder with your python script.
You can load the model by this:

```
import cv2    
from cv2 import dnn
prototxt = 'deploy.prototxt.txt'    
caffemodel='res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel'     
model =  cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe( prototxt, caffemodel)
```

Or you can check here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deep-learning-with-python-opencv/
it offers a way to to import the model directly, by using the

```
cv2.dnn.createCaffeImporter
```

Hope that helps.